# 'I haven't played for four months' or 'I didn't play for four months?'

Tags: tense, past-tense, time

Today I played a video game with my friends that I used to play always before four months from now, so the context with my friends was :

> A: Why don't you play well?
>   B: Man, I didn't play for four months

So I wondered if my usage (didn't play for four months) was proper and correct since I meant that during four months before today I didn't play a single match. I hope my text is clear.

Comment: Welcome! I guess it is nicer to show the effort you'd already made. For example, when I am not sure the usage of a word, I usually look up the definition/explanation and examples [on a dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) or other trusted reference. And then I might ask some question based on that. That would help answerers know what you've understood and what not.

Answer (score 2):

If you played regularly until four months ago, *I haven't played for four months* is appropriate.

*I didn't play for four months* would mean that there was a four-month period in the past when you didn't play.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence

> I haven't played for four months

means you have not played the game in the four most recent months – until today.

---

This sentence

> I didn't play for four months

means that some time in the past there was a *period* of four months during which you did not play the game.

> I didn't play for four months and when I started again, I was out of practice.

Comment: I appreciate your answers,

Comment: But i still wonder.. If i said (i didn't play for the last four months) would it work too??   since I am talking about the period(the last four months) which was before today (because today I played the game with my friend)

Comment: No, it's I **have not** played.

Comment: What if the period of not playing was before last monday (if i played on monday), what would i say?

Comment: I have not played since Monday, and, I did not play on Tuesday.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't get me.. What i meant is : supposing i played that game on monday (while there was no playing during four months right before that monday) and now I wanna refer that in a context... How would i say that?

Comment: If you are referring back to when you played last Monday, "I had not played for four months."

Comment: Aaahaa exactly.. Thanks so much for your answer 